# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db5012717913.hosting-data.io' (11001)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to MYSQL db server using the code below.

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector
import connection
conn = connection.MySQLConnection(
           host='*****', username='****', password='*****',
           database='****', port=3306)
```

But it is raising the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\OneDrive - ASB-McM UK Construction\Desktop\Anjali\Scripts>  & 'C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '53639' '--' 'C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\OneDrive - ASB-McM UK Construction\Desktop\Anjali\Scripts\fetchData.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 291, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown MySQL server host 'db5012717913.hosting-data.io' (11001)
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main     
    run()
  File "c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file 
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\OneDrive - ASB-McM UK Construction\Desktop\Anjali\Scripts\fetchData.py", line 9, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='db5012717913.hosting-data.io',
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1181, in connectb\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1181, in connect
    self._open_connection()                                                     b\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 296, in _open_connection
  File "C:\Users\InfoASB-McMConstruct\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lion
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db5012717913.hosting-data.io' (11001)
```

Can someone help me parse the stacktrace, and assist in finding a solution to the problem.

Comment: could you please format your errors so it is easier to read the question?

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question means that your python code wants to use a MySQL server located on the host machine with DNS name `db5012717913.hosting-data.io`. But that hostname is not in DNS.

Obtain the correct hostname for your MySQL server and put it into the `host` parameter in your connection constructor.